# How do I add a device to my provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, provisioning, adhoc

It looks like the Apple's provisioning page has changed on me.  I do not see a button for "add device" under my distribution profile anymore.  Am I blind?

Comment: Apple completely redid this section of the Developer portal. I'm seeing the same issue. There appears to be no way to edit the devices of existing adhoc provisioning profiles. Create a new one with the devices you want and delete the old one.

Comment: This is fixed now. You can now edit the devices of an AdHoc distribution provisioning profile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have played around new interface and found slow in nature but extremely organized. Check below images for your requirement.

[image]

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: This only works for development profiles. The current interface does not allow you to edit the devices of an AdHoc distribution profile.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, in that case your suggestion (creating new adhoc provisioning profile) will work.

Comment: Hopefully Apple fixes this oversight soon.

Comment: Yeah another nightmare for APPLE developers from APPLE.

Comment: It's fixed. You can now edit the devices of an AdHoc Distribution provisioning profile.

Answer (score 2):

I can create **development** provisioning with added device but not for **distribution** provisioning profile.

1. I created a distribution provisioning profile without device in IOS development center.
2. download it and drag it to iTunes library with my device connected to my computer.
3. and click sync in iTunes for my device.

There my device is added to the provisioning profiling.