# My iOS app just working on my developer devices other phones can't install(Phonegap)

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, provisioning-profile

My iOS app just working on my developer devices other phones can't install I'm using phonegap. Other devices can download but when install get full its sticking in install. I think Problem in the Provesion or certificate.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't added the other devices to your provisioning profile, you will need to.

Also, take a look at TestFlightApp.com to help with the app distribution process during testing.

Comment: But i can't add all devices on the world I cant use .ipa I cant upload app store like this

Comment: The provisioning profile is irrelevant for apps in the App Store. The .ipa file is re-signed by Apple.

Comment: I Want make app without app store from phonegap anypne can download with qrcode. But now Just I can download.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all devices you want to test on into provisioning profile you are using.

Here is a good answer how to do it:

[How do I add a device to my provisioning profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892927/how-do-i-add-a-device-to-my-provisioning-profile)

You have to keep list of devices you are using for development only during development phase. 
Apple is protecting themselves from you publishing application outside Appstore.

For submitting app to Appstore you need to use Distribution certificated - than everyone can install it - but only when downloading from Appstore - you won't be able to install that build outside Appstore flow.

During development you are only allowed to add up to 100 devices on your account. On enterprise account however there is an option to release "in-house" build - which allows you to install app on many devices - but you are not allowed to use that to distribute an app.

Comment: But i can't add all devices on the world I cant use .ipa I cant upload app store like this