# How can I test apn on iphone with only wifi

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I'm guessing that my test iPhone automatically closes wifi connections when it goes to sleep stopping my apn. I don't want to buy a line at at&t to test push notifications on a junk phone. How can provision my phone to accept push notifications over wifi.

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892927/how-do-i-add-a-device-to-my-provisioning-profile

Comment: You simply can I have been testing Push on my iPOD since forever. But If it closes wify connection then that is the problem to take care of.